# How to make stacked bar chart in Python?

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn

I have multiple categorical data (tool_id) in my data set and each has total count tested per day. I would like to make a stacked barplot where total count per tool_id that are stacked in a day for the whole month.
What python libraries can be used to easily plot a stacked bar chart and how to code it? I have tried seaborn but looks like it does not have stacked bar chart capability, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can use Matplotlib or Plotly, a Google search and you can find it easily

Comment: `matplotlib` is pretty much the standard: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html `plotly` is probably more intuitive. https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/

Comment: Seaborn does not have one-liner support for making stacked bar charts, but this can be done easily with a combination of pandas and seaborn. Try `dataframe.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)` and see the [`df.plot` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).